# OverridePendingTransition is not working on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I've seen other threads with this issue, but none of them has worked for Android TV.

I have an Activity A, which calls Activity B. I'm doing a fade animation programmatically on exit.

```
Intent startRegisterIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(LoginActivity.this, R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left).toBundle();
            startActivity(startRegisterIntent, bundle);
```

Also, i used this way but it did not work.

```
Intent startRegisterIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right,R.anim.right_to_left);
            startActivity(startRegisterIntent);
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you share with the community what question are you asking?

Comment: My question is that what is the problem and how can i solve it? @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0